# What are best practices for using SVG icons on Android?

Tags: android, svg, icons

I am about to create my first Android **native** (so not browser based) app and looking for some good practices regarding icon creating/provisioning.
Since it should support multiple devices/resolutions I thought it is best to use SVG to create them. There is at least this lib: http://code.google.com/p/svg-android/ that promises to offer support for SVG on Android.

So far, I have not found resources describing the usage of this or another library as a means to render SVG Icons on the device, so I am a bit reluctant in using it. The best I have seen so far is using SVG as the source format for pre-rendering png based icons in different resolutions.

So my questions is: Are SVG icons a good option to use directly on the device without a png pre-rendering step (does it work at all), and if, why does nobody seem to use this approach?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For Android older than Lollipop, your best practice for SVG on Android is going to be to use a tool to convert your SVG to PNG at the size(s) you're interested in. Existing SVG support for Android is not comprehensive of what you're likely to find in an SVG file, and even if it were, the support is not built into the OS so using them directly for icons is definitely out.

Beginning with Lollipop (API 21) see [What are best practices for using SVG icons on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647770/what-are-best-practices-for-using-svg-icons-on-android/29229005#29229005). Thanks to @MarkWhitaker @AustynMahoney for pointing this out.

Comment: Androidify uses this library and it looks quite comprehensive. The lib seems to be able to produce Pictures and Drawables. Would it be possible to use this to create a custom icon class leveraging this?

Comment: If the icon you're referring to is what shows up in the launcher, no. Android doesn't allow you to specify a method to generate the icon, it only permits you to identify the icon by its resource.

Comment: I am most interested in icons on buttons but I guess it is the same as for the launcher icons...Too bad :( Even Symbian has support for SVG icons....

Comment: If the library you're working with can process the SVGs you have well, you can make it work for buttons but not through the standard Android API; you'll need to create a custom button view. Around 12-18 months ago I used the library you linked and at that time it had trouble with many SVGs I had created in Inkscape or downloaded from various places. Perhaps its support has improved since then, but I recommend testing it with the exact SVGs you plan to use before you write a lot of custom code for it.

Comment: Seems like the library has not evolved much from the time of the first check-in.
Did you remember saving them as plain SVG or Inkscape SVG (contains meta information that are sometimes irritating to other programs)?
I am about to give it a try...

Comment: I recall having tried both formats. I don't recall specifics of what would not work, however.

Comment: This answer does not seem to apply anymore. Following http://caniuse.com/#search=svg most browsers (including mobile ones) now support SVG, although not many support all SVG effects, and almost none support neither SVG favicon nor fonts.

Comment: @ywarnier I haven't kept up with Android so I've no idea what has changed in 3 years... but your reasoning for this answer no longer applying does not mesh -- the question is specifically not dealing with browsers, but rather native Android usage (its application icons). Now, if the operating system itself supports SVG for its icons and/or generic application displayed resources, I would agree with your comment.

Comment: This answer is definitely not correct now. http://stackoverflow.com/a/29229005/116938

Comment: Its supports now in prelollipop too:
Android Support Library 23.2 Support Vector Drawables and Animated Vector Drawables

vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

Comment: outdated answer

Answer (score 49):

From Lollipop (API 21) onwards, Android defines the [**VectorDrawable**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html) class, for defining drawables based on vector graphics. [Android Studio 1.4 adds the "Vector Asset Studio"](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2015/09/android-studio-14.html) to make them easier to work with, including an SVG import feature and a new Gradle plugin that generates PNG versions of VectorDrawable icons at build time for API 20 and earlier. There's also [a third-party tool for converting SVGs to VectorDrawables](http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/). Bear in mind that although vector drawables can be defined in XML, the file format is not SVG and not all SVG files can be successfully converted. Simple graphics like icons should work OK.

If you still need to generate PNGs yourself, you'll need to generate your icons [at various resolutions](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html). For ease of generating those PNGs I design icons as SVG and then export to the various sizes using [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) which is free and cross-platform. It's got some nice features for designing icons, including the Icon Preview view (see below), and it generates nice crisp PNGs.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately the SVG Import function is very, very basic.

Comment: The Android team has released backwards compatibility support for Vector Assets in Android Studio 1.4. I have updated the answer to reflect this. http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/09/android-studio-14.html

Comment: tutorial link is missing/leading to this page

Answer (score 31):

This is what we are using to transform a SVG file into multiple resolutions. For example, to generate the launch icon: `svg2png -w48 icon.svg`

```
#!/bin/bash -e
# Transforms a SVG into a PNG for each platform
# Sizes extracted from
# http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html

[ -z $2 ] && echo -e "ERROR: filename and one dimension (-w or -h) is required, for example:\nsvg2png -w48 icon.svg\n" && exit 1;
FILENAME=$2
DEST_FILENAME=`echo $2 | sed s/\.svg/\.png/`
FLAG=`echo $1 | cut -c1-2`
ORIGINAL_VALUE=`echo $1 | cut -c3-`

if [ "$FLAG" != "-w" ] && [ "$FLAG" != "-h" ]; then
    echo "Unknown parameter: $FLAG" 
    exit 1
fi

# PARAMETERS: {multiplier} {destination folder}
function export {
  VALUE=$(echo "scale=0; $ORIGINAL_VALUE*$1" | bc -l)
  CMD="inkscape $FLAG$VALUE --export-background-opacity=0 --export-png=src/main/res/$2/$DEST_FILENAME src/main/svg/$FILENAME > /dev/null"
  echo $CMD
  eval $CMD
} 

export 1 drawable-mdpi
export 1.5 drawable-hdpi
export 2 drawable-xhdpi
export 3 drawable-xxhdpi
export 4 drawable-xxxhdpi
```

Answer (score 16):

Good news everyone! Since android support [library 23.2](http://android-developers.blogspot.hu/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html) we can use svg-s till back to **API level 7**!

If you wanna be compatible backwards only till Lollipop (API 21) check [Mark Whitaker's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29229005/3162918) answer, but if you want to go below you need to add these lines to your build.gradle:

```
// Gradle Plugin 2.0+ (if you using older version check the library announcement link)
android {  
    defaultConfig {  
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
    }  
}
```

Also keep in mind that:

- instead of `android:src` you need to use the `app:srcCompat` attribute in ImageViews.
- you cannot use svg-s in StateListDrawables or other xml drawables, create them programmatically instead.
- you cannot use the `android:background` attribute or `View.setBackgroundResource()` function, use the `View.setBackground()` instead.
- you cannot use svg-s in case of Notifications.

Comment: I've done this, but i only see the svg on devices with api level > 21. what is wrong here?

Comment: Are you using color attributes in you svg? could you create a new question  and insert the svg and your build.gradle file there?

Comment: @Morteza check this answer also, if it's still not working at you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36661438/3162918

Answer (score 8):

Since **nacho-coloma**'s answer helped me, I've taken his excellent script and made it slightly easier to use on a daily basis.

First:

1. Create directory `drawable-svg` next to your `res` directory.
2. Place your svg files and this script in `drawable-svg`.
3. Make the script executable.
4. Run it.  In Ubuntu you can simply double-click it in Nautilus and make it run in a terminal.

And later when you get new svg files:

5. Place new svg files in `drawable-svg` and run the script again.

By default it will do what you want: Scale every svg file into png files and put them into `../res/drawable-mdpi`, `../res/drawable-hdpi` etc.

The script takes two parameters:

1. The svg file pattern to scale, default: `*.svg`
2. The base directory for put, default `../res/` (i.e. your `res` directory with the above mentioned setup).

You can experiment by scaling a single svg into pngs in the current directory like this:

```
$ ./svg2png test.svg .
```

Or simply process all images:

```
$ ./svg2png
```

I guess you could place the `drawable-svg` inside the res directory, but I haven't looked into what gets wrapped up in the final APK.  Also, my svg files have `-` in their names, which Android doesn't like, and my script takes care of renaming the png files to something valid on Android.

I'm using ImageMagick for the conversion which is slightly more standard that Inkscape (though I liked the approach).  Both methods are included in the script for reference.

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

scalesvg ()
{
    svgfile="$1"
    pngdir="$2"
    pngscale="$3"
    qualifier="$4"

    svgwidthxheight=$(identify "$svgfile" | cut -d ' ' -f 3)
    svgwidth=${svgwidthxheight%x*}
    svgheight=${svgwidthxheight#*x}

    pngfile="$(basename $svgfile)" # Strip path.
    pngfile="${pngfile/.svg/.png}" # Replace extension.
    pngfile="${pngfile/[^A-Za-z0-9._]/_}" # Replace invalid characters.
    pngfile="$pngdir/$qualifier/$pngfile" # Prepend output path.

    if [ ! -d $(dirname "$pngfile") ]; then
        echo "WARNING: Output directory does not exist: $(dirname "$pngfile")"
        #echo "Exiting"
        #exit 1
        echo "Outputting here instead: $pngfile"
        pngfile="$qualifier-${svgfile/.svg/.png}"
    fi

    pngwidth=$(echo "scale=0; $svgwidth*$pngscale" | bc -l)
    pngheight=$(echo "scale=0; $svgheight*$pngscale" | bc -l)
    pngdensity=$(echo "scale=0; 72*$pngscale" | bc -l) # 72 is default, 

    echo "$svgfile ${svgwidth}×${svgheight}px -> $pngfile ${pngwidth}×${pngheight}px @ $pngdensity dpi"

    convert -background transparent -density $pngdensity "$svgfile" "$pngfile"
    #inkscape -w${pngwidth} --export-background-opacity=0 --export-png="$pngfile" "$svgfile" > /dev/null
    #convert "$svgfile" -background transparent -scale ${pngwidth}x${pngheight} "$pngfile"
}



svgfiles="$1"
svgfiles="${svgfiles:=*.svg}" # Default to input all *.svg in current dir.

pngdir="$2"
pngdir="${pngdir:=../res}" # Default to place output pngs to ../res, ie. ../res/drawable-hdpi etc.

for svgfile in $svgfiles; do
    echo "Scaling $svgfile ..."
    scalesvg "$svgfile" "$pngdir" 0.75 drawable-ldpi
    scalesvg "$svgfile" "$pngdir" 1    drawable-mdpi
    scalesvg "$svgfile" "$pngdir" 1.5  drawable-hdpi
    scalesvg "$svgfile" "$pngdir" 2    drawable-xhdpi
    scalesvg "$svgfile" "$pngdir" 3    drawable-xxhdpi
    scalesvg "$svgfile" "$pngdir" 4    drawable-xxxhdpi
done

echo -n "Done."
read # I've made it wait for Enter -- convenient when run from Nautilus.
```

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to convert your SVG assets into TTF font type. Include the font on your app and use it that way. This does the trick for monochromatic simple shapes.

There are several free conversion tools.

- http://fontastic.me
- https://onlinefontconverter.com
- http://www.freefontconverter.com

Answer (score 5):

Android Support Library 23.2
Support Vector Drawables and Animated Vector Drawables

1. add `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` to your build.gradle file.
2. Use  `app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add"` instead of `android:src="..."` or `setImageResource()` for your ImageView

http://android-developers.blogspot.sk/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html

Answer (score 3):

SVG icons are not a good option to use directly on a device if they need to be scaled to many different sizes, which is usually why you'd want to use vector format in the first place. A large icon will never scale down gracefully because, well, computer displays are made out of pixels. So the lines of the vector image may get aligned "in between pixels", creating a blurry border. Moreover, large icons need more details than small icons, which need very few details. A detailed icon does not look good in very small size, and a simple icon does not look good when scaled into very large size. I recently read an excellent article on this by a professional UI designer: [About those vector icons](http://www.pushing-pixels.org/2011/11/04/about-those-vector-icons.html).

Comment: You can control those things to a certain extent with `shape-rendering`. Support is sparse, though.

Comment: Thanks @Joey, that's good to know. However, even that doesn't allow you to specify that an element should be dropped altogether if the image is rendered as small enough.

Comment: Indeed. Although for icons in Android apps the most pressing concern is probably just to supply the icon in half a dozen different sizes and I haven't seen many apps that fine-tune each size. It's also less relevant the higher your pixel density is.

Comment: Random thing that I just thought of: The varying icon sizes in apps are usually due to different pixel densities of the target device – thus they all appear at roughly the same *visual* size. Thus they actually *don't* need to be more or less detailed depending on the size. At least not in this context. I'm currently using SVG as source format for icons in two Android apps at work and the only thing you *might* need to pay attention to is aligning edges to pixel boundaries for the baseline size (mdpi). Android also suggests that icons use at least two pixels for lines at baseline size.

Comment: @Joey Good point! But I assume you still need to convert your SVG icons to PNGs? Have you tried how the icons would look like if you just scaled down the largest PNG icon instead of rendering the SVG icon in different sizes? I doubt there's much difference, but it'd be great to be wrong. :)

Comment: I'm using Inkscape to render them in the necessary resolutions; since our artist draws vector icons anyway that's the easiest approach. It also allows to generate color of opacity variations on the fly (e.g. enabled/disabled icon pairs), which is a *huge* benefit of SVG. The difference when downscaling the largest PNG is small, but subtly visible (the edges are not *quite* as crisp because you're downscaling the antialiasing as well).

Comment: Vector icons don't have any drawbacks vs raster ones. Just as with bitmaps, you can also include multiple versions of vector images, each for a different target resolution. In addition, thatr article discusses artifacts that appear in extremely low resolution environments. Those environments are speedily fading into oblivion.

Comment: "Just as with bitmaps, you can also include multiple versions of vector images, each for a different target resolution." Then what's the point of using vector images at all?? Seems like there would be no difference compared to the process of creating bitmap images then.

Comment: You would only need one version for extra-low resolutions and one for all others. vs what, 5-6 different bitmaps you have to provide for Android right now? Besides, why limit supported image formats: let the **user** decide what format they prefer.

Answer (score 2):

I've just started using [Victor](https://github.com/trello/victor), an open source library by Trello, to convert SVG files to PNG files of the various required resolutions during build time.

PROS

- You won't have to run a script or tool to create various PNG files every time you change or add an icon. (You do need to hit Rebuild in Android Studio when you've added a new svg file or renamed an existing one)
- No PNG's in your source, so there's less clutter.

CONS

- The only downside I've seen so far is that Android Studio doesn't yet recognize generated resources in XML, so you'll get some red warnings in your XML files and you don't have autocomplete for your SVG based drawables. It builds fine though, and this issue should be fixed in a future version of Android Studio.

If you use SVG generated by http://materialdesignicons.com/ be sure to either download the whole file, or copy from the 'SVG File'-tab when choosing 'View SVG'

Answer (score 1):

svg is awesome.
who want use svg:

right click on drawable "new/Vector Asset" choose "material icon" for default icons and "locale SVG file" for your file in your computer hard drive and in "resource name" type name for svg file then click on "next" button and "finish"

and you can use that in drawable.
fillcolor must be hard code.

simple example

navigation_toggle.xml

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:pathData="M3,18h18v-2H3v2zm0,-5h18v-2H3v2zm0,-7v2h18V6H3z"/>
</vector>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never had much luck running Linux shell scripts in Cygwin on Windows.  So here is a batch file that does what Nacho Coloma's bash script does.  One small difference, is that this batch file requires both an input and an output file name, as in "svg2png -w24 input.svg output.png".

Set up an "svg" folder in your project's src/main directory and copy your SVG files and this batch file to that folder, per Stephan's instructions.  Run the batch file from the svg folder.  If you're on 32-bit Windows, then you will likely need to change the path to Inkscape to use "Program Files (x86)".

```
@echo off
echo Convert an SVG file to a PNG resource file with multiple resolutions.

rem Check the arguments
set temp=%1
set switch=%temp:~0,2%
set pixels=%temp:~2%
if not "%switch%"=="-w" (
if not "%switch%"=="-h" (
echo Error:  Invalid image width or height switch.  Use -w or -h, with target image size in dp appended.
goto :error
))
echo %pixels%| findstr /r /c:"^[1-9][0-9]*$" >nul
if errorlevel 1 (
echo Error:  Invalid numeric image size.  Image size must be a positive integer.
goto :error
)
if "%3"=="" (
echo Error:  Not enough arguments.
goto :error
)
if not "%4"=="" (
echo Error:  Too many arguments.
goto :error
)

call :export %1 %2 %3 mdpi
call :export %1 %2 %3 hdpi
call :export %1 %2 %3 xhdpi
call :export %1 %2 %3 xxhdpi
call :export %1 %2 %3 xxxhdpi
exit /b

:export
rem parameters: <width/height> <input-file> <output-file> <density>

set temp=%1
set switch=%temp:~0,2%
set pixels=%temp:~2%

if %4==mdpi set /a size=%pixels%
if %4==hdpi set /a size=%pixels%*3/2
if %4==xhdpi set /a size=%pixels%*2
if %4==xxhdpi set /a size=%pixels%*3
if %4==xxxhdpi set /a size=%pixels%*4

echo %size% pixels ../res/drawable-%4/%3
"C:\Program Files\Inkscape\inkscape.exe" %switch%%size% --export-background-opacity=0 --export-png=../res/drawable-%4/%3 %2
exit /b

:error
echo Synopsis: svg2png -w^<width-pixels^>^|-h^<height-pixels^> ^<input-file^> ^<output-file^>
echo Example:  svg2png -w24 "wifi white.svg" wifi_connect_24dp.png
exit /b
```