# How to convert a png file to xml resource by Android?

Tags: android, xml, png

I want to convert my png file to xml resource that can be accepteed by android.
I converted it by using the website below.

https://convertio.co/fr/png-svg/

Then I downloaded it then put it in resource directory and changed type to xml, but android didn't accept it of course.

Comment: This site seemed to convert the png to svg a little better. https://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-svg

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Easiest way to use SVG in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30923205/easiest-way-to-use-svg-in-android)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can import a svg asset and convert it into a vector.

Click on new vector asset and you will have two options , psd and svg. Import your svg file and it will be stored as a xml file.

Answer (score 11):

In current Android Studio version (3.6 rc1), you can import png image directly.
**File**-> **New**-> **Image** **Asset**.

In the **Asset Type**, select **Image**, provide path to your image file and click on **Next** and **Finish** buttons.

Android Studio would do the conversion for you.

Comment: I am selecting my PNG file for the foreground tab in Image Asset - but its not creating the `ic_launcher_foreground.xml` file. It is creating the `ic_launcher.xml` and the `ic_launcher_round.xml` - but if I use PNG files for either foreground or background, the corresponding xml files not being generated. If I change to the asset type to `color` or `art clip`, it will generate the foreground/background xml files. The problem for PNGs is that in the `ic_launcher/ic_launcher_round` xml files, both reference the foreground/background xml files, which don't exist causing the build to fail.

Comment: @rolinger : What do you want to use the png file for?