# How to use Font Awesome Icons in BottomNavigationView in Android

Tags: android, font-awesome, bottomnavigationview

I want to use Font Awesome Icons in `BottomNavigationView` 's icons. Also I want to change its color in the `Selector` . I tried many solutions but I didn't find any materials about that .

Here is my `BottomNavigationView`

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/bottomNav"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        />
```

Implementation in `MainActivity`

```
 private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            return false;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

In native development, the "font-awesome icons" isn't a good choice if you can download "SVG / PNG / URL" you can apply it to the view.

For native android, this is a good alternate
https://material.io/resources/icons/?icon=print&style=baseline

Comment: what will I do with the SVG Icon ?

Comment: you can create a vector drawable and set it as background 
for your reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39266840/7209822

Comment: Please can I know how is SVG looks like ? it's an image ? or URL ?

Comment: SVG is a scalable vector drawable. it's easy!  For now, just refer this article
https://www.androidhive.info/2017/02/android-working-svg-vector-drawables/