# How to import png without background android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, photoshop, android-vectordrawable

I want to be able to use external images in my android app,but i don't know how to deal with them,in the best case scenario they have a grey background:

[image]

How do i remove the grey background or any background to have a clean icon like the clip art that already exists in android studio(I already tried with apps and it's still drawing the background)

Comment: PNG images are bitmap. Clip arts are vectors. You can try importing the .SVG vector version of this image instead to android studio and it will be converted to a vector xml

Comment: I tried this and it still has a background

Comment: Please make sure the image is .svg vector and not png and follow this to import. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67056210/7093155 I think the problem with the PNG you are using is that the background is not entirely transparent. If you are certain it is, then setting the background with ```android:background="@android:color/transparent" ```should work

Comment: I used an image wihout a background,converted to svg online and it worked,thanks,but what if it does have a background,what can i do,how can i remove it

Comment: You should post an answer instead of comment so i can accept your answer if you want.

Comment: Alright! For your other question, I think the only way to remove a background from png would be to edit on a design software and remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure the image is .svg vector and not png and follow this to import. stackoverflow.com/a/67056210/7093155

I think the problem with the png you are using is that the background is not entirely transparent. If you are certain it is, then setting the background with `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`