# How to use VectorDrawables in Android API lower than 21?

Tags: java, android, svg, android-vectordrawable

I am working on an Android project and I chose `<vector>` to display icon because it is adaptable and dynamically, however, I just can run this app on devices running Android, which have API 21 or higher. My question is how can I use `<vector>` on lower Android version i.e. API 14 or kind of. Thanks!

```
<!-- drawable/ic_android_debug_bridge.xml -->
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:height="48dp"
    android:width="48dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24">
    <path android:fillColor="@color/primaryColorDark"
        android:pathData="M15,9A1,1 0 0,1 14,8A1,1 0 0,1 15,7A1,1 0 0,1 16,8A1,1 `0 0,1 15,9M9,9A1,1 0 0,1 8,8A1,1 0 0,1 9,7A1,1 0 0,1 10,8A1,1 0 0,1 9,9M16.12,4.37L18.22,2.27L17.4,1.44L15.09,3.75C14.16,3.28 13.11,3 12,3C10.88,3 9.84,3.28 8.91,3.75L6.6,1.44L5.78,2.27L7.88,4.37C6.14,5.64 5,7.68 5,10V11H19V10C19,7.68 17.86,5.64 16.12,4.37M5,16C5,19.86 8.13,23 12,23A7,7 0 0,0 19,16V12H5V16Z" /></vector>
```

Comment: Actual info on how to use vectors - http://stackoverflow.com/q/40678947/7045114

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Vector Drawables are now backward compatible, it's just a matter of upgrading your gradle version to 1.4.0-beta3 or higher, and upgrade your IDE :

> We are also excited to offer backwards compatibility for your vector
>   assets in Android Studio 1.4. Once you have a vectorDrawable image in
>   your res/drawable, the Gradle plugin will automatically generate
>   raster PNG images for API level 20 and below during build time. This
>   means you only need to update and maintain your vector asset for your
>   app project and Android Studio can take care of image conversion
>   process.

http://android-developers.blogspot.com.uy/2015/09/android-studio-14.html

Comment: This is not entirely true. It will work only for imageView, and for the rest it will crash on old Android versions.

Comment: @androiddeveloper is there a solution to make it work for other views like EditText, and Buttons?

Comment: @RedM Yes, but only in code (Java/kotlin). Not in XML (of any kind), as it might cause crashes. To get VectorDrawable of the support library by code, use  `AppCompatResources.getDrawable` . Do not use `ResourcesCompat` or `ContextCompat` for it. Read here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48237058/878126

Answer (score 101):

With the support library 23.2, the true support for Vector Drawables has been provided all the way down to API v7.
It is recommended to disable the previous version of the support, which rendered PNG during build-time, by adding

```
// Gradle Plugin 2.0+
 android {
   defaultConfig {
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
 }
```

to the `build.gradle` file.

The implementation is fairly simple. Just use the new **srcCompat** attribute on Drawables (under app namespace!):

```
<ImageView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add" />    // <= this is new
```

Vector Drawables are also supported in cases like TextView's `drawableLeft` property.

Source: [library announcement](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.at/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html)

However, I would still recommend something like [Iconics library](https://github.com/mikepenz/Android-Iconics), [AndroidSVG](https://github.com/BigBadaboom/androidsvg), or another font-icon or SVG solution for the full SVG-standand vector support.

Comment: How do you do this programmatically?

Comment: If somebody have crash with android:drawableLeft you can try workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40523623/2557258

Comment: Yeah, I love you. Jokes apart, this is the perfect solution, thanks! Please if you gonna use this be aware `app:srcCompat != android:srcCompat`, you must use `app:` prefix in here.

Answer (score 97):

**VectorDrawable are supported pre-Lollipop via the Support Library**, but the way to use them depends on the version of Support Library you have. And it may not work in all cases.

I've made [this diagram](https://medium.com/@ferrand.d/can-you-and-should-you-use-vector-drawables-a-cheatsheet-32a2e1cc2ecf) to help (valid for Support Library 23.4.0 to - at least - 25.1.0).

[image: VectorDrawable cheatsheet]

Comment: This is the best answer ever.

Comment: Unfortunately, build-time PNG generation doesn't support references to other resources, and will fail if you use things like `android:fillColor="@color/dialog_button_text"` in your vector drawables (so excluding the support library costs you more than just KBs). Error message points to http://developer.android.com/tools/help/vector-asset-studio.html for details.

Answer (score 44):

I found solution! For those who search solution with TextView and other "android" namespace attributes.
First of all this is necessary:

```
android {  
   defaultConfig {  
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
    }  
 }
```

And in application class define this:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
    }
```

Now you can use `app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add"` but if you try to use `android:background=` or `android:drawableLeft=` it will crash app with "Error inflating" exception.

We can create wrapped drawable `ic_add_wrapped.xml` for this vector:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_add"/>
</layer-list>
```

And now it will work with any property like drawableLeft or background. Just set `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_add_wrapped.xml"`.
WARNING! THIS IS A WORKAROUND SOLUTION. So you use it for your own risk.

Comment: Does it work on all Android versions? Even old ones? Also, does it generate the "ic_add" as an image? If so, it misses the point of using vectors.

Comment: @androiddeveloper It work on all Android versions. Even old ones. Does app:srcCompat= generate the "ic_add" as an image?

Comment: I asked if the flag in the gradle file generates the "ic_add" as an image. If it does, of course it will work on all Android versions, but it misses the point of vectors.

Comment: @androiddeveloper I really don't know if it generates an image. I tried to set small (12dp x 12dp) vector drawable to the background of some view with hardcoded big size (200dp x 200dp) and it looks smoothly and nice (looks like vector not as scaled bitmap). How to check if it generates image?

Comment: just search for the file, either within the APK file itself, or in the folders of the app. I think it can be found, for example, on "...app\build\generated\res\pngs\debug\drawable-hdpi"

Comment: @androiddeveloper I extracted .apk file and double checked all directories in res folder. There are no .png generated files from my drawable wrapped as I described. There are only .xml files. Can you try this trick and confirm that it work as expected?

Comment: OK, I now remember why I didn't use this solution: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegate.html#setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(boolean) . "This feature defaults to disabled, since enabling it can cause issues with memory usage, and problems updating Configuration instances. If you update the configuration manually, then you probably do not want to enable this. You have been warned." . It's not recommended to use this feature. Also, as I remember, it could have some issues when having the VectorDrawable inside LayerDrawable on old Android versions.

Comment: @androiddeveloper It's better than just a crash.

Comment: Yes, that's why you shouldn't use what you wrote. It's better to have extra png files, than having a crash on devices due to using this unfinished and buggy support library code, which also lacks many basic operations

Comment: @androiddeveloper It's better not use unfinished and buggy Android OS.

Comment: Again, the support library docs say it's recommended you  should not use the function you used, because it can cause issues. The Android OS can handle images very well, on all Android versions. By "unfinished" I meant that the code development has stopped in a problematic phase, so it's dangerous to use it. Also, as I wrote, I remember it lacks the capability of being used in LayerDrawable.

Comment: @androiddeveloper So you offer not to use vectors at all?

Comment: No. I suggest that you use them in basic icons in the app itself, especially if you choose to use the flag that won't create images for you. You should be careful not to use the vectors in complex cases (like layerDrawable). Always check your app on pre-M versions of Android.

Comment: And also try to avoid the special, un-recommended, call to "AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true)"

Comment: @androiddeveloper Without this workaround it does not work. So if you think that better to replace vector drawables by .png images then feel free to post your own answer to this question.

Comment: As the docs say, it's limited to certain usages. The basic one that should work fine, is for ImageView to set its image . Read here: http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html . They even marked the removed functionality with strikethrough line. Adding the function you called is not recommended. It can crash the app due to high memory usage on certain cases

Comment: They even wrote : "As of plus.google.comAndroid Support Library 23.3.0, support vector drawables can only be loaded via app:srcCompat or setImageResource() " . In short, use it with caution, only in simple cases.

Comment: @androiddeveloper Now please scroll up to the top of the page and read question. Then scroll down to the bottom of the page and press "Add Another Answer". Type "DO NOT USE VECTOR DRAWABLE" and press enter.

Comment: Why? I didn't say not not use it. I just said to use it carefully, and only in basic cases. If you wish to use it in all cases, you can disable the flag, and the images will be auto-generated, but this will miss the point of using it on old Android versions.

Comment: The `layer-list` wrapping trick doors not work in remote views (notifications, appwigets), which makes sense :-).

Comment: This been bugging me for so long time in pre lollipop devices.Thanks a tons...!!

Comment: @Debasish Say thanks for Google and their best practices of implementing software. Of course it's this solution its a dirty workaround and many of people already said it in comments.

Answer (score 20):

you need use android Support Repository 30+ if you using android studio
and need android support library 23.2.1+ if using Eclipse.

check your `build.gradle` (project) if using version 2.0+ add below code in your `build.gradle` (app)

```
// Gradle Plugin 2.0+  
 android {  
   defaultConfig {  
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
    }  
 }
```

and: if using version 1.5 add below in your `build.gradle`(app)

```
// Gradle Plugin 1.5  
 android {  
   defaultConfig {  
     generatedDensities = []  
  }  

  // This is handled for you by the 2.0+ Gradle Plugin  
  aaptOptions {  
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"  
  }  
 }
```

here is sample code for use vector icon:

```
<ImageView  
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
  app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add"
  tools:ignore="MissingPrefix" />
```

or

```
<ImageButton
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:background="@android:color/transparent"
  app:srcCompat="@drawable/camera"
  tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Vector Drawables are also supported in cases like TextView's `drawableLeft` property. but it worked api 22+ to me and i still dont know how it will work for low api.

Also keep in mind if you want to be compatible below API 21:

- you cannot use the `android:background` property in xml or `View.setBackgroundResource()` function. You need to use the `View.setBackground()`.
- you cannot use the svg-s in StateListDrawable xml-s or other xml drawables, you have to generate them programmatically.
- you cannot use svg-s in case of notifications.

Comment: For TextView, it will crash.

Comment: @androiddeveloper Here you are: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40523623/2557258

Comment: complete answer :). that is what i m looking for.

Comment: Dude you've saved from changing all my SVGs to PNGs well done sir

Answer (score 19):

When you need to add VectorDrawable (created from SVG) programatically, you can do it like this:

```
icon = VectorDrawableCompat.create(resources, R.drawable.ic_map_black_24dp, null)
```

Comment: Wait, this means we can use SVG files in the project? No need to convert them to VectorDrawable in the IDE ?

Comment: Of course, we need. R.drawable.ic_map_black_24dp here is a result of SVG-source conversion.

Comment: what is the resources argument in the snippet above?

Answer (score 9):

For lower version compatible,

1. add the below in gradle,

   ```
   android {  
      defaultConfig {  
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
       }  
    }
   ```
2. add the below code in onCreate() in your application class,

   ```
   @Override
       public void onCreate() {
           super.onCreate();
           AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
       }
   ```
3. In xml for imageView,

   ```
   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/imageViewMessage"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@color/transparent"
       app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_success"/>
   ```
4. If you want to change the image source programmatically use this,

   ```
   imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
   ```

Comment: AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true); is this necessary ?

Comment: What about ```EditText``` where I want to use ```drawableStart``` ?

Answer (score 4):

I had an issue where my vector images would show up but would be completely black, this was due to an issue where you can't reference color resources in the vector xml file.

So instead of `@color/primaryColorDark` you have to use the actual color e.g. `#212121`

Answer (score 2):

Just to make @2Dee's answer complete:

VectorDrawable cannot be used on API 20 and lower. The official method generates pngs, which then become BitmapDrawables, which breaks the idea of vector graphics.

Personally I prefer svg's over xml vectors:

- such graphics can be exported right from Illustrator or other popular software
- svg supports transformations, text, masks and other things properly
- true scallable vector graphics on all platforms
- smaller size and faster builds

To use vector graphics you can try https://github.com/BigBadaboom/androidsvg . It's an svg reader and svg-compatible ImageView.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Android Studio 3.0.0 you can set

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

in gradle.properties

https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/6mj8di/android_studio_30_canary_6_released/

Answer (score 2):

You can use programatically ..to set `drawableLeft` to your `editText` or `textView`

like

```
Drawable tick_drawable = VectorDrawableCompat.create(getResources(), R.drawable.green_tick, null);
    if (tick_drawable != null) {
        tick_drawable.setBounds(0, 0, tick_drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),tick_drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
    }
```

And to drawable left like this..

```
editText.setCompoundDrawables( tick_drawable , null, null, null );
```

Comment: getting tick_drawable value null on android 5.1

Answer (score 1):

after setting **vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true** in gradle default  and         **AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);** in activity on create

To avoid crash with **android:drawableleft in Textview**, set drawble left to the textview programitically 
for examlple:

```
 textview.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.movie, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I also found the same issue. And I did:

> vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
>
> AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
>
> textview.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.movie, 0, 0, 0);

It is good. But after that, I got an error that the resource not found.
So I found it's better to add a vector image according to the SDK version.

**Finally, this solution became good is for me:-**

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
    textview.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, AppCompatResources.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.movie), null);
} else {
    textview.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.movie, 0);
}
```

- I hope, it will help someone.