# 23.2.0 set vector drawable as background in 4.X

Tags: android, android-support-library

I am super excited about the new possibility to set vector drawables to layouts using the `app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon"` attribute introduced in support-library 23.2.0.

But I wonder how I can fetch one of this drawables programmatically or set is as background.

I thought about something like:
`ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.icon)`

Is this even possible?

Comment: I never tried so I'm just guessing, but it seems that there's a static method on VectorDrawableCompat called `createFromResource(Resource, id);` that should work. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/34cbdb2/v7/vectordrawable/src/android/support/v7/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawableCompat.java

Comment: Doesn't seem to be there with 23.2.0 in Android Studio.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Okay, I managed it myself. Thanks for @Budius for pointing me in the right direction.

The Answers lays in [VectorDrawable#create()](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/34cbdb2/v7/vectordrawable/src/android/support/v7/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawableCompat.java)

```
Resources resources = context.getResources(Resources, int, Theme);
Theme theme = context.getTheme();
Drawable drawable = VectorDrawableCompat.create(resources, R.drawable.drawable, theme);
```

More input:
[How to use vector drawables in Android API lower 21?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34417843/how-to-use-vector-drawables-in-android-api-lower-21)

Comment: There is not a xml way like `app:srcCompat` for view to use `VectorDrawable` as background. The only way to use `VectorDrawable` as a background pre android lollipop may be **VectorDrawableCompat**, thanks for share.