# cant use VectorDrawableCompat in dependencied library

Tags: android, vector, android-support-library

i'm using some library from maven, i already have this in gradle(Android Studio)

```
dependencies {
    //...other librarys
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
}
```

I want to use this for compat VectorDrawable as src **and background** of ImageView on old sdk.
but it seem like nothing work.

#### in layout xml:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

and

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/svg_head"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/header"/>
```

it would be a unexpected namespace prefix app error, if i ignore(add tools:ignore attr), it could not be built successfully.

#### in java code:

i wanna do this for compat background
[23.2.0 set vector drawable as background in 4.X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35915974/23-2-0-set-vector-drawable-as-background-in-4-x)

```
Drawable drawable = VectorDrawableCompat.create(getResources(), R.drawable.header, getTheme());
```

but class

```
VectorDrawableCompat
```

and

```
AppcompatDrawableManager
```

it can not find the class completely(only show red name, no any other prompt)

I used other library well, what happened about this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For VectorDrawableCompat and AppCompatDrawableManager, you need at least support library v23.2.0

So change to

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
```

See [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.nl/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html) android develer blog post about how to further set it up with gradle.

Comment: Ah...i update recyclerview but ignored this. But exception with NavigationView, so i update support.design too. And then i cant findviewbyid to the ImageView...What should I do further?(ImageView in a NavigationView as slid menu, all in mainactivity)

Comment: @matsuiCao I don't know, that sounds like a different problem than what your question was about

Comment: thanks : ).btw, even you know, navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findviewbyid(R.id.xxx) to find a component in header of navigationview(app:headerlayout="layout/header" in xml)