# Support library VectorDrawable Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: android, android-support-library, androiddesignsupport, android-vectordrawable

I am using Design Support Library version **23.4.0**. I have enabled the gradle flag:

```
defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
```

I am using build tools version **23.0.2**, but still, I am getting `Resources$NotFoundException` on KitKat or lower.

It is occurring when I use `android:drawableLeft` or `imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.drawable_image)`.

And yes, I am putting this on every activity where I am using drawables

```
static {
    AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
}
```

Is this a bug of the support library?

Comment: facing same problem as you .did you got any solution for android:drawableLeft ?

Comment: @Sayem No. I had to remove the graphic from the button altogether. Though you can provide separate png as drawable.

Comment: yes.. i already did it same as your suggestion.

Answer (score 89):

It took 3 separate things for me to get this to work using **support library 23.4.0**:

1. Add this to `build.gradle`

   ```
   defaultConfig {
       vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
   }
   ```
2. Add the following to **onCreate** of your `Application` class

   ```
   AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
   ```

   (From the reference of this link - "https://stackoverflow.com/a/45582033/10752962")

   In **API less then 21**,use this line before `setContentView()`;
3. For all XML views in which you are setting a vector drawable replace

   ```
   android:src
   ```

   with

   ```
   app:srcCompat
   ```

   and in the code replace this:

   ```
   imageView.setImageResource(...);
   ```

   with

   ```
   imageView.setImageDrawable(...);
   ```

Comment: does this apply even if my activity is based on AppCompatActivity? AppCompatActivity already uses AppCompatDelegate.

Comment: Simply use `AppCompatImageView` instead of `ImageView`. Problem solved. No need to keep pngs for lower versions. Even `srcCompat` is not needed.

Comment: I've done steps 1 to 3 (on the 3rd step used `app:srcCompat`). However, I still see an exception `XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #4: invalid drawable tag vector`. It looks like the `vector` tag in the XML is not recognized on this KitKat device ?

Comment: `AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);` this was the killer line of code fo me. I had to add that in my application.

Comment: why replace `setImageResource` with `seImageDrawable`?

Comment: If you use `imageView.setImageResource(...)` then `AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true)` is not needed. Tested with 25.3.1 support library.

Comment: With the new androidX libs, I only had to use "app:srcCompat" to fix the crash. Everything else stayed the same. Only used the XML. For ref. the ress. was: "@drawable/ic_done_white" that only crashed in 4.4. Thx

Answer (score 65):

To complement some of the answers here: **backward-compatible support for VectorDrawables comes with a price and doesn't work in all cases**.

In which cases does it work? I've made [this diagram](https://medium.com/@ferrand.d/can-you-and-should-you-use-vector-drawables-a-cheatsheet-32a2e1cc2ecf) to help (valid for Support Library 23.4.0 to at least 25.1.0).

[image: VectorDrawable cheatsheet]

Comment: It DOESN'T work with `setImageResource` for KitKat (4.4.4) (and lower I guess), only this works https://stackoverflow.com/a/35918375/7767664

Answer (score 32):

Try using:

```
imageView.setImageDrawable(VectorDrawableCompat.create(getResources(), drawableRes, null));
```

You don't have to add `AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);`
this way.

Just inflate your vector drawables using VectorDrawableCompat and you're all set.

Comment: This has 2 args instead of 3: `AppCompatDrawableManager.get().getDrawable(context, resId);`

Answer (score 25):

We had the same issue. Vector drawables were not visible on Kitkat. I solved this issue by adding `AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);` to the onCreate method of Activities.

Before that dont forget to add:

```
defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
```

and call setImageResource for the view that you use the vector drawable. My view is ImageButton. I have Android SDK build tools version 23.0.3

Comment: My problem is that even `AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);` is not working. The same ResourceNotFound exception.

Comment: @Arka you may try calling in onCreate method of Activities.

Comment: You should be able to add it to the onCreate of you application class. That seems to be working for me.

Answer (score 16):

Sorry for being late to the party but this answer may help users who want to enable the flag *AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);* for all activities.

**1. Create a class which extends to Application (android.app.Application)**

```
public class MyApplicationClass extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
    }
}
```

**2. Head over to Manifest.xml and add the following line to your  tag**

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplicationClass"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    ...
</application>
```

**3. Add the following code above onCreate in MyApplicationClass.java**

```
// This flag should be set to true to enable VectorDrawable support for API < 21
static
{
    AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
}
```

**Complete code for MyApplicationClass.java**

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate;

/**
* Created by Gaurav Lonkar on 23-Dec-17.
*/

public class MyApplicationClass extends Application
{
    // This flag should be set to true to enable VectorDrawable support for API < 21
    static
    {
        AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
defaultConfig {
  vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
```

use this in app.gradle

Then use `AppCompatDrawableManager` to setDrawable and getDrawable. Works for me

Answer (score 7):

Support for vector drawables in places like `android:drawableLeft` was disabled in support library 23.3. It was announced on [Google+](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/iTDmFiGrVne):

> we’ve decided to remove the functionality which let you use vector
>   drawables from resources on pre-Lollipop devices due to issues found
>   in the implementation in version 23.2.0/23.2.1. Using app:srcCompat and setImageResource()
>   continues to work.

Links to issues:

- https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=205236
- https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=204708

However, if you can live with those issues, in 23.4 you can re-enable this functionality using [AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegate.html#setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(boolean)).

If you're curious how this works, the best person to learn from is Chris Banes, who authored this functionality. He explains in detail [on his blog](https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-age-of-the-vectors-91cbafa87c88#.m3mout5ru).

Answer (score 5):

change

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.drawable_image)
```

to

```
imageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.drawable_image));
```

if you want to use vectordrawable in xml, use this:

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/drawable_image"
```

Comment: Your method  setImageDrawable works. But still button drawableLeft not working.

Comment: This causes crashing on older devices.

Comment: This doesn't work. Use one of the other answers here instead.

Comment: you should have this vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true on your build.gradle and this AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true); on your onCreate of your Application Class or {AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true); } on your activity. Check the question. He added those lines on his code before he ask

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem long ago, it did not work by setting

`vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true`

only worked when I created the "mipmap" folder, and the code used

`imageView.setImageResource (R.mipmap.drawable_image)`

It has more Info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28065267/mipmap-vs-drawable-folders)

Answer (score 1):

[image: API 16 animation]
**Inflating Drawable's**

`` `VectorDrawable` `` and `` `AnimatedVectorDrawable` `` in this support library can be inflated in this way:

- Calling static `getDrawable()` methods:

```
//This will only inflate a drawable with <vector> as the root element
VectorDrawable.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_arrow_vector);

//This will only inflate a drawable with <animated-vector> as the root element
AnimatedVectorDrawable.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_arrow_to_menu_animated_vector);

// This will inflate any drawable and will auto-fallback to the lollipop implementation on api 21+ devices
ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.any_drawable);
```

*If inflating the Drawable in java code, it is recommended to always use `ResourcesCompat.getDrawable()` as this handles Lollipop fallback when applicable. This allows the system to cache Drawable ConstantState and hence is more efficient.*
The library has the following morph (bi-directional) animations :

Play-Pause morph animation

Play-Stop morph animation

Arrow-Hamburger menu morph animation

As you can see, I produced the above image on my `API 16` phone:

```
import com.wnafee.vector.compat.AnimatedVectorDrawable;
mdrawable = (AnimatedVectorDrawable) AnimatedVectorDrawable.getDrawable(this.getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.consolidated_animated_vector);
```

Look at the github **README** for `vector-compat` here: https://github.com/wnafee/vector-compat
This will fix your problem (down to `API 14`) if you merge it with your app module's `build.gradle` `dependencies` (usually at the end of file):

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//Trying to FIX Binary XML file line #2: invalid drawable tag animated-vector
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
//not needed
//  compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.wnafee:vector-compat:1.0.5'//*******holy grail *******https://github.com/wnafee/vector-compat
//  Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-animated-vector-drawable:25.0.0
//not needed
//  compile 'com.android.support:support-animated-vector-drawable:25.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not put your vectors in `drawable-anydpi` 
, old devices does not support that

put them in `drawable`

Comment: This Works for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my particular case, I had this problem because I was using a drawable selector as the image resource with several vectors in the selector, as in:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/vector_select_blue"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/vector_select_black"/>
    .
    .
    etc
</selector>
```

Yes, pretty bad, but didn't know better at the time.

So, the right way of doing this is using the tint property in your vector file, as in:

```
<vector ..vector properties..
        android:tint="@color/vector_color_selector">
              <path ..path properties../>
</vector>
```

(You can also use the app:tint attribute in the AppCompatImageView)

And now, your vector_color_selector file should have the colors you want, as in:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@color/blue"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/black"/>
    .
    .
    etc
</selector>
```

I hope this helps someone if previous answers didn't work for you. Stating the obvious, but I must say that you still need to set vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true in gradle, use AppCompatImageView and use app:srcCompat or setImageDrawable + AppCompatResources.getDrawable to avoid any troubles with the vector compat library.

Answer (score 0):

Use `AppCompatImageView` instead of `ImageView` as said by Harish Gyanani in comments , it works fine with this for me.

[Official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageView)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and actually what was missing is I was using app:srcCompat on AppCompatTextView except of AppCompatImageView.

The way I have found the problematic part:

My error looks like:

```
Fatal Exception: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException
Resource ID #0x7f0700d1
```

Here are the steps I followed the resource id of the mentioned drawable :

- APK Analyzer -> classesXXX.dex
- In this dex file I opened the directory of my apps package name and went to R$drawable file
- R$drawable -> Show as byte code.
- Search for ID [0x7f0700d1] (check your own ID)
- Find the image and check for all the usages (CMD + F7) of the resource
- Fix

Hope it will help somebody.