# Is that right to make android.view.InflateException by using Vector drawables in android:background: line in a ImageView

Tags: android, user-interface, inflate-exception

I am facing `android.view.InflateException` in my app for some particular devices, in others phone it works fine. But i don't know why. Many others says that this problem occurs for drawable vector image. I am using vector image in `android:background= ""` line. is that make this `InflateException`.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/nameLayoutMain"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:background="@drawable/shadow_164949">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:background="@drawable/draw_phone"
        android:id="@+id/im1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_phone"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/linearLayoutName"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/linearLayoutName" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutName"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/im1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/im1"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/im1">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtPhoneShow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/my_phone_number"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtPhone"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txtPhone" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtPhone"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="01612548792"
                android:textColor="@color/toolbar1"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txtPhoneShow"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you show me xml code of drawable vector?

Comment: share error logcat..

Comment: Can you please check this. It contains my drawable vector image, my XML, my error and my Java code.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7XpFVYwQlMYcHc3Q2lHWWU3cUE

Comment: Nazmus, I know it's a while back but do you remember if you solved this?

Comment: @n00dles, yes, i can remember. Don't use SVG or Vector image as a background and always use app:srcCompat="@drawable/------"

Comment: Yeh, I guessed that in the end. Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have added `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` inside `defaultConfig` in `app/build.gradle`.

Like

```
defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        ....
 }
```

**EDIT 1**
In order to support `vector` in API less then 21. Also add this in `onCreate` method of Activity before `setContentView`.

```
AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Yes, I added this line in build.gradle

Comment: @NazmusSaadat Just added one more.

Answer (score 0):

Use color code replace of color name from color.xml in your drawable vector xml like below;

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="#4396e6"
    android:pathData="M21,19V5c0,-1.1 -0.9,-2 -2,-2H5c-1.1,0 -2,0.9 -2,2v14c0,1.1 0.9,2 2,2h14c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2zM8.5,13.5l2.5,3.01L14.5,12l4.5,6H5l3.5,-4.5z"/>
```