# Resource not found Exception for devices on API 24 and above

Tags: android, android-appcompat

My application uses vector drawables and it works fine on all devices below API level 24. I have already enabled `android.defaultConfig.vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` in gradle file and below is the code for the imageView

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
            </android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView>
```

programatically I am changing the images dynamically like this `view.imgView.setImageResource( iconImage.get( position ) );` iconImage is an ArrayList that holds different images and I populate it with this code

```
private void prepareList() {

    iconImage = new ArrayList<>();
    iconText = new ArrayList<>();

    iconImage.add(R.drawable.ic_new_profile);
    iconText.add( LanguageSwitch.myProfile );

    iconImage.add( R.drawable.ic_new_contributions );
    iconText.add( LanguageSwitch.contributions );

    iconImage.add( R.drawable.ic_new_benefits );
    iconText.add( LanguageSwitch.benefits );

    iconImage.add( R.drawable.ic_new_claims );
    iconText.add( LanguageSwitch.claims );

    iconImage.add( R.drawable.ic_new_dependents );
    iconText.add( LanguageSwitch.dependants );

    iconImage.add(R.drawable.ic_new_cards );
    iconText.add( LanguageSwitch.mycard );

    iconImage.add(R.drawable.ic_new_facility );
    iconText.add( LanguageSwitch.facilities );

    iconImage.add( R.drawable.ic_new_preauth );
    iconText.add( getResources().getString( R.string.preuath ) );

    iconImage.add(R.drawable.ic_new_contact_us );
    iconText.add( LanguageSwitch.contact_us );

}
```

My gradle file looks like this :

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx.xxx.xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 32
        versionName "2.0.3"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        android.defaultConfig.vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        applicationId "com.ngenx.nhif"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'

    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

And finally the log file :

```
Process: com.ngenx.nhif, PID: 5233
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.ngenx.nhif:drawable/ic_new_profile with resource ID #0x7f0800d3
    Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_new_profile.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0800d3
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:725)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:571)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:767)
        at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:525)
        at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:358)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:198)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:186)
        at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:85)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:93)
        at com.ngenx.nhif.MainMenuAdapter.getView(MainMenuAdapter.java:76)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2362)
        at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1065)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
        at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1619)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
```

Comment: add `AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);` in your Activity section

Comment: Or  `defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }` in your `build.gradle`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37615470/support-library-vectordrawable-resourcesnotfoundexception

Comment: Still not working, I've added AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true); before setContentView, is this ok?

Answer (score 0):

```
defaultConfig { vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true }
```

was working fine, the problem I had was some corrupt svg icons. I realized it after replacing them with some old ones which were working fine.