# AppCompatRadioButton using vector asset

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable, android-radiobutton

I am having problems on 4.4 devices with using Vector Drawables. First of all i switched my RadioButton to AppCompatRadioButton so i could use vectors. Thing is i am not sure how i am supposed to use them as i have indicator in xml (indicator_selector) which is basically just on and off assets for click state:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/on" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/of" android:state_checked="false"/>

</selector>
```

As this are vector drawables should i change them to

```
app:srcCompat=@drawable/on?
```

And when creating buttons in code should i use any other specific way for vector drawables or no? This is my current code:

```
AppCompatRadioButton radioBtn = new AppCompatRadioButton(activity);
radioBtn.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.indicator_selector);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically i was not able to make it work with XML files, i just wrote code for states like

```
StateListDrawable stateListDrawable = new StateListDrawable();
        stateListDrawable.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_checked}, checked);
        stateListDrawable.addState(new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_checked}, unchecked);
```

and then set it up to AppCompatRadioButton and it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have

`AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled( true ); // enable SVG`

In your app class ?

Comment: I included it in gradle only?

Comment: You need to create an App class that extends Application then in the onCreate method you put this code

Comment: see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37615470/support-library-vectordrawable-resourcesnotfoundexception/41699357

Comment: Hmm okay but what should be in indicator ? Where i put drawable states? android:drawable or something else?

Comment: app:srcCompat=@drawable/indicator_selector in your xml file