# App Crashes only on particular computer. With NoClassDefFoundError error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-vectordrawable

I got an App. It launches on other computers buy my computer does not. It does not work even if make apk. If I create apk of the same app from other computer it works if I make from this it does not. It gives me the following error

I have tried:
1) Clean-Rebuild
2) Invalidate and restart
3) Uninstall / reinstall Android studio
4) Use multidex from here https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex
5) Tried native emulator / genymotion / real device

I have tried all (as i think) things which could cause the problem. So Please if want to minus that question put the comment what is wrong it could help me improve the quality of my questions.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager$VdcInflateDelegate.createFromXmlInner(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:775)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:366)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:198)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:191)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:753)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:196)
        at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:86)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:260)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:182)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:520)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:71)
        at com.myApp.base.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:69)
        at com.myApp.devicemanager.DMActivity.onCreate(DMActivity.java:29)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myApp.mobile.pm.payday"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.ext.supportLibraryVersion"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation ("com.myApp.mobile.pm.common:app:$rootProject.ext.commonVersion") {
        exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation'
        exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core'
        exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind'
    }

    annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:$rootProject.ext.butterknifeVersion"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"

}
```

Comment: Would you add your WHOLE `build.gradle` (this with dependencies)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the version of android on simulator/device you are testing, you might need to add this line to your gradle

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
 }
```

source: [Android Vector Drawable Documentations](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources).

Comment: Did you check this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/37864531/5528269

Comment: The thing is that it works with the same code and config on other computer. So the problem somewhere in this particular comp not code i guess. But yes I tried all that manipulation in code