# Android: Vector Asset does not appear

Tags: android, vector

I'm using `Vector Asset` on my application. The icon I'm used does not appear in one of my phones and I don't know how to solve this issue.
One of the mobiles has android version 8.1 (API 27) and the icon appears and the other has version 6.0.1 (API 23) and the icon does not appear. I've searched, the Vector Asset is supported since version 20.
What can I do to the icon appears on my android version 6.0.1 phone?

Vector asset code:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="54dp"
    android:height="54dp"
    android:viewportWidth="35.68696"
    android:viewportHeight="35.68696">
      <group android:translateX="5.843478"
          android:translateY="5.843478">
            <path
                android:strokeWidth = "1"
                android:strokeColor="#A0A0A0"
                android:pathData="M19.43,12.98c0.04,-0.32 0.07,-0.64 0.07,-0.98s-0.03,-0.66 -0.07,-0.98l2.11,-1.65c0.19,-0.15 0.24,-0.42 0.12,-0.64l-2,-3.46c-0.12,-0.22 -0.39,-0.3 -0.61,-0.22l-2.49,1c-0.52,-0.4 -1.08,-0.73 -1.69,-0.98l-0.38,-2.65C14.46,2.18 14.25,2 14,2h-4c-0.25,0 -0.46,0.18 -0.49,0.42l-0.38,2.65c-0.61,0.25 -1.17,0.59 -1.69,0.98l-2.49,-1c-0.23,-0.09 -0.49,0 -0.61,0.22l-2,3.46c-0.13,0.22 -0.07,0.49 0.12,0.64l2.11,1.65c-0.04,0.32 -0.07,0.65 -0.07,0.98s0.03,0.66 0.07,0.98l-2.11,1.65c-0.19,0.15 -0.24,0.42 -0.12,0.64l2,3.46c0.12,0.22 0.39,0.3 0.61,0.22l2.49,-1c0.52,0.4 1.08,0.73 1.69,0.98l0.38,2.65c0.03,0.24 0.24,0.42 0.49,0.42h4c0.25,0 0.46,-0.18 0.49,-0.42l0.38,-2.65c0.61,-0.25 1.17,-0.59 1.69,-0.98l2.49,1c0.23,0.09 0.49,0 0.61,-0.22l2,-3.46c0.12,-0.22 0.07,-0.49 -0.12,-0.64l-2.11,-1.65zM12,15.5c-1.93,0 -3.5,-1.57 -3.5,-3.5s1.57,-3.5 3.5,-3.5 3.5,1.57 3.5,3.5 -1.57,3.5 -3.5,3.5z"/>
      </group>
</vector>
```

I've included `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` in `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 0):

I use these in one of my projects and at one point could not get it to work on older versions. I added this to my MainActivity and it worked.

```
 static {
    AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
}
```

My post may have been incomplete, the link where I found what worked for me was here.  It may be worth checking out:

[SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37615470/support-library-vectordrawable-resourcesnotfoundexception)

Comment: any where in the main activity  -- its like a field