# Why isn't the vector drawable for some country flags getting rendered?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-vectordrawable, country-codes

My app makes use of vector drawables to display country maps. This works fine for most countries, but for a few, Cyprus for example, the drawable isn't getting rendered:

[image]

However, I know that the vector drawable for Cyprus is good:

[image]

Can anyone see why some flags get rendered and others do not? I'm targeting Android SDK 29.

Comment: Well,i think it's not a big deal.
Sometimes during development this happens and it will automatically solved like when you close and re-open file,if this is another issue then tell us what's the problem

Comment: @VivekThummar It is a big deal because my app crashes when it tries to render any of the images in question.

Comment: Ohk,so i don't know much about this but sometimes app crashes because of Vector drawables.
Try given link - https://stackoverflow.com/a/37864531/10752962
If this also not helps you then sorry for this.

Comment: @VivekThummar Thanks again for the suggestion, but I doubt this is the problem because my app renders the other images just fine.

Comment: @FractalBob Did you ever find a solution to the problem? I am facing the same issue right now and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Sorry, Veselin, i never was able to resolve it.