# ImageSpan on pre lolipop returns null

Tags: android

I'm trying to render a drawable between two strings using SpannableStringBuilder using the code below:

```
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
        builder.append(getResources().getString(R.string.menu_about_crafted))
                .append(" ")// Left margin
                .append(" ");
        builder.setSpan(new ImageSpan(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_pixel_heart),
                builder.length() - 1, builder.length(), 0);
        builder.append(" "); // Right margin
        builder.append(getResources().getString(R.string.menu_about_author));

        textView.setText(builder);
```

it works perfectly on devices running lolipop and above but for the devices running pre lolipop it crashes and return NullPointerException.

Here's the error messages i receive:

```
E/sms: Unable to find resource: 2131165296
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.text.style.DynamicDrawableSpan.getSize(DynamicDrawableSpan.java:81)
    at android.text.TextLine.handleReplacement(TextLine.java:842)
    at android.text.TextLine.handleRun(TextLine.java:937)
    at android.text.TextLine.measureRun(TextLine.java:414)
    at android.text.TextLine.measure(TextLine.java:293)
    at android.text.TextLine.metrics(TextLine.java:267)
    at android.text.BoringLayout.isBoring(BoringLayout.java:308)
    at android.widget.TextView.makeSingleLayout(TextView.java:6140)
    at android.widget.TextView.makeNewLayout(TextView.java:6032)
    at android.widget.TextView.onMeasure(TextView.java:6389)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.onMeasure(AppCompatTextView.java:501)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:1227)
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1572)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:733)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:805)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:401)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I also have vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary enabled for drawable backward compatibility in my gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, apparently i needed to add `AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);` in order for drawables to be supported on devices lower than API 21.

if using fragments add `AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);` in`onCreateView()` method before any other views.

if using activity add `AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);` in `onCreate()` before `setContentView()`

(Reference link - "[Support library VectorDrawable Resources$NotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37615470/support-library-vectordrawable-resourcesnotfoundexception)"