# SVG on Android below API 23

Tags: android, svg

I´m trying to get SVGs on an older API, but when I start the activity where the SVG is located, the app brokes. It is working on a 6.0 device, but not on 4.2.2

it comes with

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class ImageView

I imported the SVG with the Android Vector Asset, also with this one http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/
But it doesen´t make a different.

This is how I call the SVG:

```
   <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/map2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

my gradle:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    applicationId "com.example.jendrik.moerder"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.2.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.+'
}
```

Does anybody has a clue?
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34417843/how-to-use-vector-drawables-in-android-api-lower-21/36661438#36661438)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know your post, because this was my source. I followed your description before I posted this question. Could you tell me what I did different?

Comment: Found my mistake. I used "android:src="@drawable/map2"
instead of app:srcCompat