# ResourcesCompat.getDrawable() vs AppCompatResources.getDrawable()

Tags: java, android, android-resources, android-theme, android-styles

I'm a bit confused with these two APIs.

**[ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(Resources res, int id, Resources.Theme theme)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/res/ResourcesCompat.html#getDrawable(android.content.res.Resources,%20int,%20android.content.res.Resources.Theme))**

> Return a drawable object associated with a particular resource ID and styled for the specified theme. Various types of objects will be returned depending on the underlying resource -- for example, a solid color, PNG image, scalable image, etc.
>
> Prior to API level 21, the theme will not be applied and this method simply calls through to getDrawable(int).

**[AppCompatResources.getDrawable(Context context, int resId)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/content/res/AppCompatResources.html#getDrawable(android.content.Context,%20int))**

> Return a drawable object associated with a particular resource ID.
>
> This method supports inflation of **vector** and **animated-vector** resources on devices where platform support is not available.

### Question

1. What is the significant difference between these two classes
   (besides **vector** inflation)?
2. Which one should I prefer to another and why?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Looking at the source code of the two methods, they seem very similar. If you don't have vectors, you could probably get away with using either one or the other.

[`ResourcesCompat.getDrawable()`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/master/sdk/extras/android/support/v4/src/java/android/support/v4/content/res/ResourcesCompat.java) will call `Resources#getDrawable(int, theme)` on APIs 21 or greater. It also supports Android APIs 4+. It is no more than this:

```
public Drawable getDrawable(Resources res, int id, Theme theme)
        throws NotFoundException {
    final int version = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (version >= 21) {
        return ResourcesCompatApi21.getDrawable(res, id, theme);
    } else {
        return res.getDrawable(id);
    }
}
```

Where-in `ResourcesCompatApi21` merely calls `res.getDrawable(id, theme)`.  This means it will *not* allow vector drawables to be drawn if the device does not support vector drawables.  It will, however, allow you to pass in a theme.

Meanwhile, the code change for [`AppCompatResources.getDrawable(Context context, int resId)`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatDrawableManager.java) eventually lands to this:

```
Drawable getDrawable(@NonNull Context context, @DrawableRes int resId, boolean failIfNotKnown) {
    checkVectorDrawableSetup(context);

    Drawable drawable = loadDrawableFromDelegates(context, resId);
    if (drawable == null) {
        drawable = createDrawableIfNeeded(context, resId);
    }
    if (drawable == null) {
        drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, resId);
    }

    if (drawable != null) {
        // Tint it if needed
        drawable = tintDrawable(context, resId, failIfNotKnown, drawable);
    }
    if (drawable != null) {
        // See if we need to 'fix' the drawable
        DrawableUtils.fixDrawable(drawable);
    }

    return drawable;
}
```

So this instance it will attempt to draw the resource if it can, otherwise it looks in the `ContextCompat` version to get the resource.  Then it will even tint it if necessary. However, this method only supports API 7+.

So I guess to decide if you should use either,

1. Do you have to support API 4, 5, or 6?

   - Yes: No choice but to use `ResourcesCompat` or `ContextCompat`.
   - No: Keep going to #2.
2. Do you absolutely need to supply a custom Theme?

   - Yes: No choice but to use `ResourcesCompat`
   - No: Use `AppCompatResources`

Comment: "Do you absolutely need to supply a custom Theme? Yes: No choice but to use ResourcesCompat" Thank you for clearing that up.

Comment: The quality of picture (resolution) with AppCompatResources is better for vector-drawable resources.

Answer (score 111):

Here is my understanding after some testing:

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(@NonNull Context context, @DrawableRes int resId)

ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(@NonNull Resources res, @DrawableRes int id, @Nullable Theme theme)

AppCompatResources.getDrawable(@NonNull Context context, @DrawableRes int resId)

VectorDrawableCompat.create(@NonNull Resources res, @DrawableRes int resId, @Nullable Theme theme
```

The first thing I see is `VectorDrawableCompat` and `ResourcesCompat` can specify a theme.

### I) Without using

`AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);` in `onCreated` of the Application class

***1) For vector images***

- API >= 21
- `ContextCompat` works well
- `ResourcesCompat` works well
- `AppCompatResources` works well
- `VectorDrawableCompat` works well
- API < 21
- `ContextCompat` **crash**
- `ResourcesCompat` **crash**
- `AppCompatResources` works well
- `VectorDrawableCompat` works well

***2) For normal image***

- In all API levels
- `ContextCompat` works well
- `ResourcesCompat` works well
- `AppCompatResources` works well
- `VectorDrawableCompat` **crash**

### II) Using

`AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);` in `onCreated` of the Application class

***1) For vector images***

- In all API levels
- `ContextCompat` works well
- `ResourcesCompat` works well
- `AppCompatResources` works well
- `VectorDrawableCompat` works well

***2) For normal images***

- In all API levels
- `ContextCompat` works well
- `ResourcesCompat` works well
- `AppCompatResources` works well
- `VectorDrawableCompat` **crash**

Comment: Good summary, but unfortunately just shows how big mess is the support library :). You have 1002345 ways to create drawable (animated or not). We should just have one unique way of doing it and if the animation is not supported they should just try to convert it to simple drawable image, but not crash the app with ResourceNotFound

Comment: So `AppCompatResources` is the only one without crashes?

Comment: very informative

Answer (score 28):

#### ContextCompat

`ResourcesCompat`, `ContextCompat` and pretty much any class from support-v4 ending with `Compat` saves you from writing `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= X)` checks everywhere. That's it. For example instead of

```
final Drawable d;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
    // Old method, drawables cannot contain theme references.
    d = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.some_image);
} else {
    // Drawables on API 21 can contain theme attribute references.
    // Context#getDrawable only exists since API 21.
    d = context.getDrawable(R.drawable.some_image);
}
```

you can write

```
final Drawable d = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.some_image);
```

The limits described in comments apply, for example

```
// This line is effectively equivalent to the above.
ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.getResources(), R.drawable.some_image, context.getTheme());
```

does not actually apply the theme attributes before Lollipop (this is said in the documentation). But you don't have to write if checks and your code does not crash on old devices because you're not actually using new APIs there.

#### AppCompatResources

`AppCompatResources` on the other hand will actually help you bring new features to old platforms (support vectors, theme references in color state lists).

> Which one should I prefer to another and why?

Use `AppCompatResources` to get consistent results with the rest of appcompat-v7 library. You'll get:

- `getColorStateList` which can resolve colors with theme attribute references (such as `android:alpha="?android:disabledAlpha"`),
- `getDrawable` which supports inflating vectors on all platforms and these vector drawables also understand theme attribute references (e.g. `android:tint="?colorControlNormal"`),
- appcompat-v7 drawables and colors like checkmarks or radio buttons will have proper colors defined by supplied context theme,
- if the above does not apply it falls back to `ContextCompat` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

API 19+ workaround

```
package com.example;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.annotation.DrawableRes;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat;

/**
 * https://stackoverflow.com/a/48237058/1046909
 */
public class AppDrawableCompat {

    public static Drawable getDrawable(@NonNull Context context, @DrawableRes int resId) {
        try {
            return AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, resId);
        } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e1) {
            try {
                return ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, resId);
            } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e2) {
                return VectorDrawableCompat.create(context.getResources(), resId, context.getTheme());
            }
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    public static Drawable findDrawable (@NonNull Context context, @DrawableRes int resId) {
        try {
            return getDrawable(context, resId);
        } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void setViewBackgroundDrawable(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Context context, @DrawableRes int resId) {
        Drawable drawable = findDrawable(context, resId);
        if (drawable != null) {
            view.setBackground(drawable);
        }
    }
}
```

Using example (MainActivity#onCreate)

```
ImageView icon = findViewById(R.id.icon);
AppDrawableCompat.setViewBackgroundDrawable(icon, this, R.drawable.bg_icon);
```