# what is the difference between setImageDrawable and setImageResource when using vector drawable?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an ImageView and vector image with a gradient tag in it. I tried displaying the image with several methods and it produced varying results in Android 21.
I have set `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` in my project.

- Using **setImageResource**(), vector image displayed successfully

  ```
  image.setImageResource(R.drawable.xarisanv2_img_success_payment)`
  ```
- Using **setImageDrawable**(**AppCompatResources**.getDrawable(), vector image displayed successfully

  ```
  image.setImageDrawable(AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.xarisanv2_img_success_payment))
  ```
- Using **setImageDrawable**(**ContextCompat**.getDrawable(xxxx)), app **crashed**.

  ```
  image.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.xarisanv2_img_success_payment))
  ```

  [image]

Could Someone explain what happening behind this? Especially about how  setImageResource can handle vector image with gradient tag.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43004886/resourcescompat-getdrawable-vs-appcompatresources-getdrawable

Comment: Thanks @GabrieleMariotti, but it did not mention anything about setImageResource. 
How setImageResource could handle vector image with gradient tag in Android API 21?

Answer (score 0):

**setImageResource()** takes an resource id **(From An Existed Resource File)** as parameter, like `R.drawable.xxx`, this resource id is an integer value.

**setImageDrawable()** takes an `Drawable` object as paramater, commonly this object is created by your code at run time, but you can also use `getDrawable(context, R.drawable.xxx)` to convert the existed `Drawble` resource file into `Drawable` object (like in your code), though it needs more code.