# Android resource not found exception for notification icon

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable, crashlytics

In my latest release, I suddenly started getting this error: `Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f080120`. The resource ID is my notification icon, which is used in one of the tabs in a ViewPager, which is displayed at startup. I am not able to reproduce the issue myself, but see a lot of new crashes in Firebase Crashlytics.

The notification icon is stored in multiple densities: [image]

The code that causes the crash:

`ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_notification_icon)`

The weird thing is that I did not change anything related to this drawable or the code in the ViewPager in this release. The best suggestion I found from searching around, was to clean and rebuild the project. I did this and uploaded a new version, but the crash reappeared.

The crash is observed on the following Android versions:

- Android 13
- Android 11
- Android 8.1.0
- Android 7.1.2

And the following devices:

- Galaxy A53 5G
- Nexus 5X
- Standard PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996)
- vivo S1
- OnePlus8Pro
- Mi 9x

**Edit:**
I can see that 44% of the affected devices are rooted. Does it mean I should not worry about the issue?

Comment: is it happening on specific Android versions?

Comment: @Lino Android 7, 8 and 11. I updated my question with the details now.

Comment: @km11 Why are you not using a vector icon (SVG) instead of png to eliminate this error?

Comment: @MDEV Because the png files have a nice shadow around the edges, which I am not able to get with SVG (at least not when converted to xml)

Answer (score 1):

We are too facing this kinda of error a lot in our app. So,By doing little bit of search, I am changing ContextCompat to AppCompatResources to get the drawables. I seriously don't know now yet it will be beneficial for our app or not but reason to change is simply because the way ContextCompat returns result  with respect to the way the AppCompatResources returns result. [ContextCompat](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/core/core/src/main/java/androidx/core/content/ContextCompat.java) is just calling context's getDrawable method which in turn calls [Resource's](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/content/res/Resources.java) getDrawable method which in turn calls ResourceImpl getValueForDensity method and finally calling a native method. Whereas AppCompatResources calls  [AppCompatDrawableManager](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/60cc94c/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatDrawableManager.java)'s getDrawable method which try different approaches  to get the drawable and eventually fallback to ContextCompat if none of the approaches work. This seems to be better candidate for me get the drawable.

AppCompatDrawableManager's getDrawable method

```
public Drawable getDrawable(@NonNull Context context, @DrawableRes int resId,
        boolean failIfNotKnown) {
    checkVectorDrawableSetup(context);
    Drawable drawable = loadDrawableFromDelegates(context, resId);
    if (drawable == null) {
        drawable = createDrawableIfNeeded(context, resId);
    }
    if (drawable == null) {
        drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, resId);
    }
    if (drawable != null) {
        // Tint it if needed
        drawable = tintDrawable(context, resId, failIfNotKnown, drawable);
    }
    if (drawable != null) {
        // See if we need to 'fix' the drawable
        DrawableUtils.fixDrawable(drawable);
    }
    return drawable;
}
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43006846/15754377) also has useful information too.

Comment: Interesting, have you applied this and observed fewer crashes afterwards? Even 0 related to the `.getDrawable()` call?

Comment: As I said, I was looking for solution of problem similar to yours , I changed most of context Compat call to AppResource Compat. Let's hope for best. Android is seriously a mess. :P

Comment: It sure is. Please report back!

Comment: Bounty awarded now. Have you experienced any issues after changing to AppCompatResources?

Answer (score -2):

ContextCompat is creating the issue

use it directly

getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_notification_icon)