# Android - support vector drawables on Motorola

Tags: android, motorola, support-vector-compat

I have a problem with rendering vector drawable on Motorola pre-lollipop phones. I tested it on Moto G and other with KitKat. Every time I start application some icons look corrupted and some are missing at all. And after each launch they are corrupted in a different way. On Lenovo, Samsung, AOSP Emulator and others with JB+ till Nougat everything is ok. Only Motorola phones can not render vector drawables with support library well. Does anybody have the same issue?

Comment: Please post your code how you are add vector

Comment: already have answer for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34417843/how-to-use-vector-drawables-in-android-api-lower-21

Comment: I am using it as documentation said. Only motorolla have such issue. Other pre-lollipop devices are ok

Comment: There are a lot of think related to support vector drawable that is not mentioned in the documentation.Even I have faced a lot of issue with it.Only if you post the code, we will be able to help you as asked by @Lokesh

Comment: Do you have a small example vector drawable that exhibits these problems? There are a variety of device-specific problems with vector drawables including scientific notation and not having a leading zero for decimal values. The linter in the latest Android Studio 3.0 Preview should point out some of these for you.

Comment: are you importing vector drawables from svg's?

Comment: yes, I am importing it fom svg and have no warnings there

Answer (score 2):

Vector Drawables are also supported in cases like TextView's drawableLeft property.
go this link [Android Studio 1.4](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/09/android-studio-14.html)

```
<ImageView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon"
```

Comment: https://medium.com/@ferrand.d/can-you-and-should-you-use-vector-drawables-a-cheatsheet-32a2e1cc2ecf

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following to onCreate() method of your Application class:

```
AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
```

From official docs:

> When enabled, AppCompat can intercept some drawable inflation from the framework, which enables implicit inflation of vector drawables within DrawableContainer resources.
>   You can then use those drawables in places such as android:src on ImageView, or android:drawableLeft on TextView.
>   This feature defaults to disabled, since enabling it can cause issues with memory usage, and problems updating Configuration instances.
>   If you update the configuration manually, then you probably do not want to enable this. You have been warned.

Answer (score 1):

In my Research I found two ways to support vector drawable on pre lollipop devices. You can try this.

You can support all devices with vector drawable with `AppCompatImageView`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                app:srcCompat=""    // your drawable declaration
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

> android.support.v7.appcompat:srcCompat
>
> Sets a drawable as the content of this ImageView. Allows the use of
>   vector drawable when running on older versions of the platform.
>
> Requires Support Library 23.4.0 or latest

Source: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageView.html#attr_android.support.v7.appcompat:srcCompat

Another way is to configure vector drawable setting in Gradle. Include the below code in your Gradle.

```
android {  
   defaultConfig {  
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
    }  
 }
```

The use `srcCompat` in your `ImageView`

```
<ImageView  
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
  app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add" />
```

Source: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html

Hope it helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use vector with ImageView, you should use **srcCompat**-AppCompatImageView. However, if you want to use vector with **drawableLeft**.. use this library  https://github.com/bsobe/vectorview

Answer (score 0):

Try this:::-

```
Drawable date = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(itemView.getContext(), R.drawable.ic_date_range_black_24dp);
etDeliveryDate.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(date, null, null, null);
```

Comment: @user3280437  have you removed src or srcCompat drawable path from xml?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @user3280437  I just said remove app:srcCompat="" or src