# SVG vector not working under API 21 when I changed progress bar's background

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-custom-view, android-progressbar, android-vectordrawable

I'm trying to change progress bar's background with SVG vector drawable and I'm using supportLibrary and that's working perfectly on API 21 and higher versions of android but under API 21 it's just crashing. Here is the logs:

```
 at com.myCompany.modules.presetshare.ui.components.MediaPlayerProgressBarCustomView.<init>(MediaPlayerProgressBarCustomView.java:23)
    at com.myCompany.modules.presetshare.ui.components.MediaPlayerProgressBarCustomView.<init>(MediaPlayerProgressBarCustomView.java:18)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
    at com.myCompany.modules.presetshare.ui.PresetShareSaveFragmentView.onCreateView(PresetShareSaveFragmentView.java:72) 
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2346) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1428) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1759) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1827) 
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2596) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2383) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2338) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2245) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:703) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_tone_slider_filled.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f08017c
```

and my custom progress bar class:

```
class AddToneProgressBarCustomView extends ProgressBar {

public AddToneProgressBarCustomView(Context context) {
    super(context);
 }

public AddToneProgressBarCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
 }

public AddToneProgressBarCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    setProgressDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.custom_add_tone_progress_bar));

 }
}
```

Progress bar XML layer-list:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@android:id/background"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_add_tone_slider" />
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip android:drawable="@drawable/ic_add_tone_slider_filled" />
</item>
```

Then I've tried to change progress bar's background with creating a shape and passing parameter to set `setProgressDrawable()`.
Like this:

```
Drawable shape = VectorDrawableCompat.create(getContext().getResources(), R.drawable.custom_add_tone_progress_bar, getContext().getTheme());
    setProgressDrawable(shape);
```

but this solution fixed only crash problem. My app isn't crashing anymore but android isn't rendering the SVG file.

Anybody have any idea to fix this problem? This issue seems like a bug to me anymore. Thank you.

Comment: Please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40523623/4748607)

Comment: @NiravBhavsar thank you for your answer but I've already tried adding `AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);` to Application class but nothing changed. Also I'm already using SupportLibrary in my project.