# Using SVG in android selector for buttons

Tags: android, svg

I am using svg for icons for `ImageView` it can be given using `app:srcCompat` But when i want to use it for `Buttons` as selector the app crashes with resource not found exception for devices with api below 21

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_enabled" android:state_enabled="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_disabled" android:state_enabled="false" />
</selector>
```

Where button_enabled and button_disabled are both svg

Comment: `the app crashes with resource not found exception` which device and API level ?

Comment: sorry for that i will update my question

Comment: @Superman it crashes for api level below 21

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the answer to my own question.
In your activity just add this static block

```
static {
    AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you to follow the below steps :-

Step 1:

[image: select svg from local folder]

Right click on drawable folder -> select New -> select Vaector Assests

Step 2:

[image: click on next]

Select Local file svg now select the path of your svg image click on next you will have now the svg image in your drawable folder

do the same thing for svg images you want to use in your application

Now use the below code for selector buttons **selector_button.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_check_circle" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_build" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_build" />
</selector>
```

I imported two svg 1st ic_check_circle and 2nd ic_build you can replace as per your needs.

In your imageView use below line

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/selector_button"
```

Comment: what if i want to use it for checkbox button tag?

Comment: @VishwajitPalankar pls see the below answer for CheckBox selection hope it will help you if not let me know.

Answer (score 2):

SVG rendering in Android was targeted for API level 21 and +. ie from Lollipop onward. Since the crash occurs in a lower version, what you require is backward compatibility for SVG .

Ideally there are two solutions here:

1. Use the **Victor** library, which supports backward compatibility. Available [[ here ]](https://github.com/trello/victor) . Also check this detailed medium article on Vector usage in Android.  [[ here ]](https://medium.com/@webalys/die-png-die-how-to-use-vector-icons-in-your-apps-d884c9c63e93#.29otlzcsc)
2. From Android support library v23.2 onward, SVG usage has been made backward compatible till API v 7. The detailed guide is available [ [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html) ]. Also see this Answer as well. [ [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38872284/4738175) ]

Answer (score 1):

Use below **selector_checkbox.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_check_circle" android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_uncheck_circle" android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_uncheck_circle" android:state_checked="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_check_circle" android:state_checked="true" />
</selector>
```

Where **ic_check_circle** and **ic_uncheck_circle** both are svg file imported from local file as i already mentioned in above steps

And in your xml file use below code for CheckBox and put **selector_checkbox.xml** file as a button and you are done

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
        android:id="@+id/appCompatCheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:button="@drawable/selector_checkbox" />
```