# How to make one side semi circled background textView?

Tags: android

I would like to make such background for my textView:

[image]

I managed to make only with outer semi circle:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/p_color" />
    <corners android:radius="24dp" />
</shape>
```

which is not good for me. I also tried to work with states list but didn't succeed with it.

Comment: what you can do is create another rectangle and then perform boolean or just use an svg of this shape as a backgound of transparent rectanlge

Comment: what did you mean with performing boolean? can you add any answer with your solution pls?

Comment: just create the shape in svg formate and then read this to know how to use the svg as background of button https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41802267/using-svg-in-android-selector-for-buttons

Comment: hm... I know to use svg as background, but I can't imagine how to create such shape via svg and drawables.

Comment: use figma for that it is pretty easy to create svg just  watch a 10 mint figma video on youtube and you will be fine

Comment: so as I understand you don't know how to create such background, thank you for your help and info :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hello my Friend,**

What you need will not create by shape Drawable, you need a custome view

in fact you need some trick to make your desired shape by custom views and use it inside a constraintlayout as background of your TextView

I coded for you by kotlin(if you need java inform me):

**first:**

make a file and name it CustomeBg copy below code put in that:

```
    import android.content.Context
    import android.graphics.*
    import android.util.AttributeSet
    import android.view.View


class CustomeBg @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    private var W = 0.0f
    private var H = 0.0f

    /////main body Rect and Paint
    private var bodyRect = Rect()
    private var bodyRectPaint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)

    //right half circle Rect and Paint
    private var rightCircleRect = RectF()
    private var rightCirclePaint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)

    //left half circle Rect and Paint
    private var leftCircleRect = RectF()
    private var leftCirclePaint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)


    init {

    }


    override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)
        W = w.toFloat()
        H = h.toFloat()

    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        // drawRect(canvas)
        var left = 0
        var top = 0
        var right = W - RADIUS_RIGHT
        var bottom = H

        bodyRectPaint.apply {
            color = BODY_COLOR_RECT
            style = Paint.Style.FILL
        }

        bodyRect.set(left, top, right.toInt(), bottom.toInt())
        canvas.drawRect(bodyRect, bodyRectPaint)


        // Draw Left half-Circle
        var left_l_circle = -RADIUS_LEFT
        var top_l_circle = 0f
        var right_l_circle = RADIUS_LEFT
        var bottom_l_circle = H

        leftCirclePaint.apply {
            color = LEFT_CIRCLE_COLOR
            style = Paint.Style.FILL
        }

        leftCircleRect = RectF(left_l_circle, top_l_circle, right_l_circle, bottom_l_circle)
        canvas.drawArc(leftCircleRect, -90f, 180f, true, leftCirclePaint)


        // Draw Right half-Circle
        var left_r_circle = (bodyRect.right) - RADIUS_RIGHT
        var top_r_circle = 0f
        var right_r_circle = bodyRect.right + RADIUS_RIGHT
        var bottom_r_circle = H

        rightCirclePaint.apply {
            color = RIGHT_CIRCLE_COLOR
            style = Paint.Style.FILL
        }

        rightCircleRect = RectF(left_r_circle, top_r_circle, right_r_circle, bottom_r_circle)
        canvas.drawArc(rightCircleRect, -90f, 180f, true, rightCirclePaint)

    }


    companion object {
        private val BODY_COLOR_RECT = Color.parseColor("#00534b")
        private val LEFT_CIRCLE_COLOR = Color.parseColor("#ffffff")
        private val RIGHT_CIRCLE_COLOR = Color.parseColor("#00534b")
        private val RADIUS_LEFT = 100f
        private val RADIUS_RIGHT = 100f

    }

}
```

**second:**

then in your main_activity layout put below XML codes:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="51dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="95dp">

        <com.example.junk2.CustomeBg
            android:id="@+id/itemSettingBg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        </com.example.junk2.CustomeBg>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hallo ich bin Custome"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/itemSettingBg"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/itemSettingBg"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/itemSettingBg"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/itemSettingBg" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Result is :
[image]

I need explain a little my codes for better understanding:
in CustomeBg there are some value:

```
companion object {
    private val BODY_COLOR_RECT = Color.parseColor("#00534b")
    private val LEFT_CIRCLE_COLOR = Color.parseColor("#ffffff")
    private val RIGHT_CIRCLE_COLOR = Color.parseColor("#00534b")
    private val RADIUS_LEFT = 100f
    private val RADIUS_RIGHT = 100f

}
```

in this file in fact we have 3 object, *two half-circle*(one for left and one for right)
and we have *one rectangular as our body*, above code explain radius for every circle and their colors, you can see body color here too

**Notice:** you can change above value for your usage my freiend