# Loading .svg image by an external link in RecyclerView adapter in android?

Tags: android, json, svg, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I have a list of .svg images from wikipedia and trying to load list of countries in my RecyclerView adapter. I tried  library  from github

1. [AndroidSvgLoader](https://github.com/ar-android/AndroidSvgLoader)    2.[Svgloader](https://github.com/ar-android/AndroidSvgLoader/tree/master/svgloader)

Although there is no problem in loading in Activity but was not able to load within RecyclerView Adapter after passing Activity as context too.

List of images are :

1. https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f3/Flag_of_Russia.svg
2. https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0d/Flag_of_Saudi_Arabia.svg
3. https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fe/Flag_of_Egypt.svg

Is there any way to load server svg images in adapter ?

Comment: what is your adapter code ? It would help to debug the issue ...

Comment: post adapter and activity code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are best practices for using SVG icons on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647770/what-are-best-practices-for-using-svg-icons-on-android)

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35507893/does-glide-have-a-method-for-loading-both-png-and-svg

Comment: @Nakul my Adapter code looks like this  https://pastebin.com/fULL3BjQ